# How calculate distance between two coordinates (from google map) using MySQL 8 ST_Distance?

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geospatial, mysql-8.0

I have a table in my database which is storing the locations from google map with the coordinates returned by them. Previously i was storing the lat and lng as decimal points and after i have upgraded the MySQL version to 8, it's been found that there are predefined data types and functions to handle coordinates and the distance calculations. 
I have created the table as below and inserted few random values from google map.

```
CREATE TABLE `Location` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lat` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lng` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `coordinates` point NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_lat_lng` (`lat`,`lng`),
  SPATIAL KEY `sk_coordinates` (`coordinates`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sample data inserted

```
INSERT INTO Location (name, lat, lng, coordinates)
SELECT 'Thayyeni Koomban', '12.33984592973732', '75.41285991668701', POINT(12.33984592973732, 75.41285991668701) UNION
SELECT 'Tejaswini river rafting', '12.29208143873455', '75.4130744934082', POINT(12.29208143873455, 75.4130744934082) UNION
SELECT 'Mossy Forest, Cameron Highlands', '4.5242225', '101.38192709999998', POINT(4.5242225, 101.38192709999998) UNION
SELECT 'Dhanushkodi Point', '9.152226599999999', '79.44291569999996', POINT(9.152226599999999, 79.44291569999996) UNION
SELECT 'KL Sentral', '3.13333', '101.68667000000005', POINT(3.13333, 101.68667000000005) UNION
SELECT 'Kozhippara Waterfalls', '11.3537295', '76.10803290000001', POINT(11.3537295, 76.10803290000001) UNION
SELECT 'Laguna Honda Hospital and Rehabilitation Center', '37.7492806', '-122.45702240000003', POINT(37.7492806, -122.45702240000003) UNION
SELECT 'Singapore Zoo', '1.4043485', '103.79302299999995', POINT(1.4043485, 103.79302299999995) UNION
SELECT 'Taj Mahal', '27.1750151', '78.04215520000002', POINT(27.1750151, 78.04215520000002) UNION
SELECT 'Sea View Point', '11.2643567', '75.76153939999995', POINT(11.2643567, 75.76153939999995) UNION
SELECT 'Club Mahindra Ashtamudi', '8.965749299999997', '76.57136119999996', POINT(8.965749299999997, 76.57136119999996) UNION
SELECT 'Kollam Beach', '8.8756778', '76.58891629999994', POINT(8.8756778, 76.58891629999994) UNION
SELECT 'Tropical Islands', '52.03892399999999', '13.748616999999967', POINT(52.03892399999999, 13.748616999999967) UNION
SELECT 'Taroko National Park', '24.15870679999999', '121.62162969999997', POINT(24.15870679999999, 121.62162969999997) UNION
SELECT 'Lake Tyrrell', '-35.2553505', '142.8419824', POINT(-35.2553505, 142.8419824) UNION
SELECT 'Karthika Regency', '10.0192948', '76.30539509999994', POINT(10.0192948, 76.30539509999994) UNION
SELECT 'Sentosa', '1.2494041', '103.83032090000006', POINT(1.2494041, 103.83032090000006) UNION
SELECT 'Kovalam Beach', '12.7902597', '80.25390390000007', POINT(12.7902597, 80.25390390000007) UNION
SELECT 'Torres del Paine National Park', '-50.9423262', '-73.40678789999998', POINT(-50.9423262, -73.40678789999998) UNION
SELECT 'Niagara Falls', '43.0828162', '-79.07416289999998', POINT(43.0828162, -79.07416289999998);
```

Understood that google coordinates uses an SRID of 3857 and hence created the following query with different combinations of lat and lng to generate the point. But none of the distance seems to be accurate.

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    lat, 
    lng, 
    ST_Distance(ST_SRID(coordinates, 3857), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.0120262 76.3586236)', 3857)) AS distance,
    ST_Distance(ST_SRID(POINT(lat, lng), 3857), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.0120262 76.3586236)', 3857)) AS lat_lng,
    ST_Distance(ST_SRID(POINT(lng, lat), 3857), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.0120262 76.3586236)', 3857)) AS lng_lat_first,
    ST_Distance(ST_SRID(POINT(lng, lat), 3857), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(76.3586236 10.0120262)', 3857)) AS lng_lat_all,
    ST_Distance(ST_SRID(POINT(lng, lat), 3857), ST_SRID(POINT(76.3586236, 10.0120262), 3857)) AS lng_lat_all_x,
    ST_Distance(ST_SRID(POINT(lng, lat), 3857), ST_SRID(POINT(10.0120262, 76.3586236), 3857)) AS lng_lat_all_y, 
    ST_Distance(ST_SRID(POINT(lat, lng), 3857), ST_SRID(POINT(10.0120262, 76.3586236), 3857)) AS lng_lat_all_z   
from test.Location;
```

[image: Result]

Am I doing it in the correct way or missing something? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure .But ST_Distance is taking two parameters .Here is three parameter.The exmple is

```js
mysql> SET @g1 = Point(1,1);
mysql> SET @g2 = Point(2,2);
mysql> SELECT ST_Distance(@g1, @g2); .
```